# Proof that $H(X) \leq \log(|A|)$ (Shannon entropy)

Tags: probability, logarithms, information-theory, entropy

The full question states:

"Show that $$H(X) \leq \log(|A|)$$
with equality if and only if $P_X$ is uniform. Hint: use the Gibbs or log-sum inequality "

I used "$A$" as the alphabet in here. My lecturer is using curly "X" which I don't know how to type in MathJax.

The equality part is rather straight forward.

Suppose $A=\{1,...,m\}$ and $P_X(x)=\frac{1}{m} \forall x$. Then of course $|A|=m$
And $$H(X)=-\sum_{x=1}^m \frac{1}{m}\log(\frac{1}{m})=-\log(\frac{1}{m})=\log(m)=\log(|A|)$$

It is the inequality part that I am not sure how to show. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any probability distributions $p, q$ on $A$, Gibbs inequality states that
$$
H(p)=-\sum_{k\in A} p(k)\log p(k)\leq -\sum_{k\in A} p(k)\log q(k)
$$
with equality iff $p=q$. Take $q$ to correspond to a uniform distribution on $A$. Then
$$
H(p)\leq -\sum_{k\in A} p(k)\log \frac{1}{|A|}=\log|A|
$$
with equality iff $p$ is a uniform distribution as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_i$s be the corresponding probabilities of the source $X$ and $q_i={1\over |A|}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots , |A|$ .  Therefore using Gibbs' inequality we obtain:$$H(X)=-\sum p_i\log p_i\le -\sum p_i\log q_i=-\log {1\over |A|}\sum p_i=\log |A|$$

For further reading, you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality